# Implement UnityAds Mediation with Admob in Android

Tags: android, admob, inmobi, unityads

I follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/unity) to integrate UnityAds into Admob via Mediation. But it was not working, whenever I start the video ads, nothing shows at all.

If I do not using mediation, and implement UnityAds in normal way, it worked.

I also noticed the UnityAdapter class, but I did not know how to use it. Currently via mediation, I also have InMobi and it is OK.

> Note: apply the mediation for the iOS version and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it worked. Instead of adding its ".AAR" file, I have to place its library zip file in our libs folder.

Made me feel really annoyed was the instruction from Google Admob Mediation, it just outdated and completely unhelpful.

For example,  I have to contact InMobi team to get their latest adapter since the SDK provided on Google Admob Mediation was just outdated.